# Query by time / date

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mongodb, parse-platform

I'm using a Parse database (pretty much a MongoDB database)

I'm trying to store information about the hours of a store.

In an example, if the store owner indicates that a sale should not happen between 4pm and 7pm, the store should not show up on a query if it is within this timeframe.

How can I organize my database to make this pattern as simple as possible?

Comment: Is there just one timeframe per day when stores should be excluded?  How about excluded days, weekends, holidays etc?  Its easy to answer about parse because it offers a date-time type and equality and inequalities on queries.  That's it.

Comment: That's a great point @danh. You are completely right to include days weekends and holidays. And that's very interesting about parse, can you explain?

Comment: Just that it's really simple.  You can query for greaterThan this_date, and lessThan that_date, but that's about it.  For anything non trivial -- which it sounds like you're heading to non-trivial -- you'll need to pull a super set of records into memory, and do computation in your app code to reduce to the desired set.  It would be worse news if you could only do this on the client, because then you'd have to transmit the superset to clients.  Small happy news there is that parse lets you deploy functions in "the cloud" so you can do an in memory reduction on their server.